# $\{x \in X\mid f_1(x) = f_2(x)\}$ is a closed set

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f_1, f_2: X \to Y$ be continuous map from a topological space $X$
> to a Hausdorff space $Y$.  Show that the set of points $\{x \in X\mid f_1(x) = f_2(x)\}$ is a closed set.

Here's what I've done so far:

To show that $D=\{ x \in X \mid f_1(x)=f_2(x)\}$ is closed, it suffices to show that $D^c=\{ x \in X \mid f_1(x)\neq f_2(x)\}$ is open. For this, consider $x\in X$ such that $f_1(x) \neq f_2(x)$. Now, since $f_1(x), f_2(x) \in Y$, $f_1(x) \neq f_2(x)$ and $Y$ is Hausdorff, there exist open sets $U_1$ around $f_1(x)$ and $U_2$ around $f_2(x)$ such that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. Now, we know that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, then for any open set $U \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. So, $f_1^{-1}(U_1)$ and $f_2^{-1}(U_2)$ are open sets in $X$ and $x \in f_1^{-1}(U_1)\cap f_2^{-1}(U_2)$, and since finite intersection of open sets is open, $V_x=f_1^{-1}(U_1)\cap f_2^{-1}(U_2)$ is an open set in $X$.

Now, I'm stuck here! Since $x$ was arbitrary point, for any $x\in D^c$, there's an open set $V_x$ and hence, we can write $D^c \subset \cup_{\alpha} V_{x_{\alpha}}$ which $\cup_{\alpha} V_{x_{\alpha}}$ is open. But I have problem with showing that $D^c$ is open!

Comment: You need show that $V_x \subset D^c $.

Comment: $g=f_1-f_2$ is continuous and $\{0\}$ is a closed set hence $g^{-1} ( \{ 0 \} )$ is closed.

Comment: @copper.hat, we are working on topological spaces, so you cannot substract $f_1$ and $f_2$, the sum is not necessarily well defined.

Comment: @Falcon Thanks for catching that, I was not paying attention. You can use the fact that the diagonal in $Y \times Y$ is closed and consider the function $f = (f_1,f_2)$ in the product topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show the reverse inclusion. For $y\in \cup_{x \in D^c} V_{x}$ there is $x^* \in D^c$ such that $y \in V_{x^*} = f^{-1}_1(U_1) \cap f^{-1}_2(U_2)$ which exactly means that $f_1(y) \neq f_2(y)$.

Comment: Oh! I see! This is because $f_1(y) \in U_1$ and $f_2(y) \in U_2$, and since $Y$ is hausdorff, $U_1 \cap U_2 =\emptyset$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 6):

Recall that a topological space $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if its diagonal is closed, that is, $D_Y\colon=\{(y_1,y_2)\in Y\times Y:y_1=y_2\}$ is closed (in $Y\times Y$ with the product topology).

The function $F:X\to Y\times Y$ given by $F(x)\colon=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is continuous as $f_1,f_2$ are continuous, so $$F^{-1}(D_Y)=\{x\in X:F(x)\in D_Y\}=\{x\in X:f_1(x)=f_2(x)\}$$ is closed, as the pre-image of closed sets under continuous function are again closed.

Let continuity do the work for you.

Comment: It's a brilliant idea! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Note the result that $D_Y$ is closed can be seen as a special case of the result, with $X=Y\times Y$ and $f_i=\pi_i:(y_1,y_2)\mapsto y_i.$ This one case shows all the others.